# Leaflet: How to get CountryCode (latLng)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, country-codes

I'm using Leaflet with OpenStreetmap (Javascript) and would like to get the country code for the given Latitude and Longitude, so that I can pass it (variable) to a function. How can I do it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There is a web service that returns a country code and takes as parameters the latitude and longitude. Check the [documentation](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#countrycode)

You should create a user account at http://www.geonames.org/login in order to use the service.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need this information sporadically, you can use the function that returns latlng coordinates for a specific country. All you have to do is move the map to a specific view of the country and you will receive coordinates in the console.log. Use this function `map.getCenter()` you can compare it with the data that this page [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/)

```js
const map = L.map('map').setView([52.0, 20.0], 7)

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map)

map.on('dragend', function onDragEnd() {
  console.log('center: ' + map.getCenter())
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

However, if you want any api to return data to you, you can use **nominatim**
One note - read the documentation because, as in all map solutions, there are some restrictions, e.g. in the number of requests per second, etc. This is important, otherwise you can get your domain blocked.

Example of use: [nominatim](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?country=Poland&format=json) you get accurate information. All you need is to provide the name of the country.

More here [nominatim.openstreetmap.org/](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search) and here [nominatim-docs](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/)

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. I would like to build a function like     

`function codeCountry (latLng){ .... var countrycode = [save here countrycode]; ......}`

this function is written in a javascript document and called in a html. Is there a way (for example via another api) to return the country code by giving  the latitude and longitude parameter?

Comment: I gave you a link to the api https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?country=Poland&format=json
All you have to do is pass the data and get the `type "administrative"` from json and you have the exact coordinates;)

Comment: I am not needing the coordinates. I'm needing the country code for the given Latitude and Longitude. Do you know if Leaflet provides a function which returns the country code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this API

```
http://api.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?lat=you_lat_value3&lng=your_lang_value&username=demo
```

And you need to create an account: `http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html`

Comment: Thank you! I am starting to learn javascript and just cant find a way to extract that value (for example from [http://api.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?lat=you_lat_value3&lng=your_lang_value&username=demo] the value 'AT'). I have tried the Fetch method but cant figure it out. Do you know how I can get this value in javascript? (like that: console.log("the value of the url"); )

Comment: fetch('http://api.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?lat=you_lat_value3&lng=your_lang_value&username=your_uszrname')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data) // Prints result from `response.json()` in getRequest
})
.catch(error => console.error(error))